# How can I detect collisions with SFML for loop over sprites within a vector?

Tags: c++, sfml

I have a vector containing sprites which I use for a wall:

```
std::vector<Sprite> wallSprites(30, Sprite(walltexture));
```

These are repeated with:

```
for (int i = 0; i < wallSprites.size(); i++) {
    wallSprites[i].setPosition(wallPosX,0);
    wallPosX += 63;
    wallSprites[i].setOrigin(0,0);
}
```

And then drawn with:

```
for (int i = 0; i < wallSprites.size(); i++) {
    app.draw(wallSprites[i]);
}
```

I then want to see if a car sprite has collided with ANY of the wall sprites. I am trying this code to iterate through all of the wallSprites, but it only detects the car hitting the last wall sprite to be drawn:

```
for (int i = 0; i < wallSprites.size(); i++) {
    if (car.getGlobalBounds().intersects(wallSprites[i].getGlobalBounds()))
    {
        crashed = true;
    }
    else
    {  // We're not colliding
        crashed = false;
    }
}
```

Where am I going wrong please?

Comment: Use a debugger to see the positions of the walls and the car.

Comment: how do you move your car?

Comment: I would probably need to see the full source code to try to find your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the car hits a wall that isn't the last one, `crashed` will be set to `true`. If it doesn't collide with the next wall, it will be set to `false` again. That's not what you want.

As such, the solution is simple:

```
for (int i = 0; i < wallSprites.size(); i++) {
    if (car.getGlobalBounds().intersects(wallSprites[i].getGlobalBounds()))
    {
        crashed = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

This assumes that `crashed` starts out `false`. It will now become `true` when it hits *any* wall, which is the desired behaviour. There's also an additional `break`, which isn't necessary for it to work, but why go on when we already know the answer?

Alternatively, depending on your code, your `crashed` variable may have become redundant with that fix, allowing you to reduce this to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < wallSprites.size(); i++) {
    if (car.getGlobalBounds().intersects(wallSprites[i].getGlobalBounds()))
    {
        handleCarCollision();
        break;
    }
}
```